# Dynamic attribute selection in Vue - previous selection is being made blank

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

The attributes data comes from an API and the attribute names are dynamic, however to make this example simpler i have put an example with an object which has `Colour` and `Size`. I was primarily trying to map data to an object `selectedAttrObj` - which has no problems, however when the second sets of attributes are selected (`Size`), the first one (`Colour`) is becoming blank. This must be due to the fact that the first `v-model="selected"` is being overwritten when second set is selected. This is a visual experience, and how I can make sure the first select stays with the selected option. Please do not try to hardcode as there could be countless number of attributes, so it needs to be dynamic (hence the reason for using `selected` for all attributes). If there is a better and simpler way of mapping the selected data to `selectedAttrObj` to avoid blanking out previous selections, please fire away! Thanks

```js
function callMe(){
    var vm = new Vue({
        el : '#root',
        data : {
         attributes : {
         "Colour": ["red", "black", "purple"],
         "Size": ["8.0", "8.5", "9.0", "9.5", "10.0"]},
         selectedAttrObj: {},
         selected: ""
         },
         methods: {
          selected_attributes(name, value) {
            this.selectedAttrObj[name] = value
            console.log(this.selectedAttrObj)
          }
         }
    })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="(item, key, index) in attributes "> {{ key }}     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td v-for="(items, key, index) in attributes">
        <select v-model="selected" @change="selected_attributes(key, selected)">
            <option v-for="name in items"> {{ name }} </option>
        </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your data variable selected to be a object and save the values based you the given key you are iterating.

Here is a snippet:

```js
function callMe(){
    var vm = new Vue({
        el : '#root',
        data : {
         attributes : {
         "Colour": ["red", "black", "purple"],
         "Size": ["8.0", "8.5", "9.0", "9.5", "10.0"]},
         selected: {}
         }
    })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
  
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="(item, key, index) in attributes "> {{ key }}     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td v-for="(items, key, index) in attributes">
        <select v-model="selected[key]">
            <option v-for="name in items"> {{ name }} </option>
        </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
    
  </div>
</div>
```